# How do I force wp_enqueue_scripts to load at the END of <head>?

Tags: plugins, wp-enqueue-script, headers, wp-enqueue-style, wp-head

I am loading scripts via `wp_enqueue_scripts` in my child theme.

The only problem is that my `style.css` script get loaded BEFORE plugin scripts, yet I need to override the CSS in the plugins with my style.css. So it needs to load AFTER plugin scripts.

I don't want to add "!important" too all of my CSS styles because that is tedious and could break some of my styling.

I tried adding a priority but it did not effect the loading order at all.

```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts', 9999);
```

I would simply like to `wp_enqueue_scripts` at the very end of the header, just before `</head>`. How can it be done? Thanks :-)

**UPDATE:**

Yay I figured it out!

Simply register the filter with:

```
    add_action('wp_print_styles', 'scripts');
```

`wp_print_styles` loads with a priority of 8, and it still places them in the header because it's a part of `wp_head`.

I figured this out by looking in wp-includes/default-filters.php, so thanks for the tip! :-)

Answer (score 5):

`wp_enqueue_scripts` is added per default with a priority of `1` to `wp_head`. See `wp-includes/default-filters.php` for details.

You can try to change the priority:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1 );
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 9999 );
```

But I don’t recommend it. There is probably a good reason for the default value. Some scripts may not work anymore when you change this.

Comment: Unfortunately, doing this causes the entire website to break.

Comment: I don’t believe that, but, yes, side-effects are inevitable.

Comment: please try to describe this and tell everyone, how this could put enqueued scripts and styles at the end of document's head, as this clearly puts them at the end of body!!

Answer (score 4):

I think the more WordPress friendly way to do this is to use [`wp_enqueue_styles()`'s](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) $deps parameter. Assuming the plugin styles are enqueued via wp_enqueue_styles() (which, admittedly, pathetically few are), you list an array of the stylesheet handles that your styles depend on and then they load afterwards.